# Like operation MYSQL using SQLBoiler and golang

Tags: go, sqlboiler

I want to Perform LIKE operation in MYSQL using SQL boiler and golang

I am using

```
github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4/queries/qm
```

.

```
clause = qm.Where(fmt.Sprintf("post.deleted_at is null"))
    queryMods := []qm.QueryMod{
        clause,
        qm.Offset(gpi.Offset),
        qm.Limit(gpi.Limit),
        orderByMod,
        qm.Load(dbmodels.PostRels.ImpartWealth), // the user who posted
    }
    if searchKey != "" {
    where := fmt.Sprintf(`user on user.impart_wealth_id=post.impart_wealth_id 
and user.screen_name like ? or user.email like ? `)
queryMods = append(queryMods, qm.InnerJoin(where, "%"+searchKey +"%", "%"+searchKey +"%"))
    }
    posts, err := dbmodels.Posts(queryMods...).All(ctx, m.db)



[]qm.QueryMod{qmhelper.WhereQueryMod{Clause:"post.deleted_at is null",
 Args:[]interface {}(nil)}, 
qm.offsetQueryMod{offset:0},
 qm.limitQueryMod{limit:1}, 
qm.orderByQueryMod{clause:"created_at desc, post_id desc"},
qm.loadQueryMod{relationship:"ImpartWealth", mods:[]qm.QueryMod(nil)}, 
qm.innerJoinQueryMod{clause:"user on user.impart_wealth_id=post.impart_wealth_id \n\t\tand user.screen_name like ? or user.email like ? ",
 args:[]interface {}{"%j%", "%j%"}}}
```

Here Like is not working.

Data is getting, but like operation not working, that is not getting the data that filter using the email or screenname.

filtering not working

Comment: Are you sure the panic's caused by `like`? A panic in Go usually outputs a stacktrace, can you include that in your question?

Comment: @mkopriva , I updated the error.. I am new to this ..  its working if I remove the code inside if searchKey != ""  this

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the stacktrace, either you have omitted it, or the code that prints the error that you have included discarded the stacktrace. Without it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Here's an example of a stacktrace: https://play.golang.org/p/ol8ECz_dYQR and notice how it points out, correctly, that the error is on line 15. (`/tmp/sandbox375163025/prog.go:15`)

Comment: @mkopriva updated the data that getting after the error

Comment: show `fmt.Printf("%#v\n",queryMods)`, i think something is nil inside.

Comment: Can you show the code for the function `github.com/impartwealthapp/backend/pkg/models/dbmodels.NewQuery`? It seems like it is calling `qm.Apply` which is then causing the panic, so it's highly likely that `NewQuery` is passing bad arguments to `Apply`.

Comment: @MiaMia mh-cbon is correct [this line](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/blob/475493476401b3fd8fd0801eece058e514d284d7/queries/qm/query_mods.go#L41) will panic only if one of the mods is `nil`. However [`qm.WhereIn`](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/blob/475493476401b3fd8fd0801eece058e514d284d7/queries/qm/query_mods.go#L309-L314) does not, under any circumstance, return `nil`. Can you show `NewQuery`? Does it, or anything in-between, modify the `queryMods` slice before passing it to `Apply`? Somewhere something must be appending `nil`.

Comment: @mkopriva

func NewQuery(mods ...qm.QueryMod) *queries.Query {
 q := &queries.Query{}
 queries.SetDialect(q, &dialect)
 qm.Apply(q, mods...)

 return q
}

Comment: @mh-cbon 

[]qm.QueryMod{qm.QueryMod(nil), 
qm.offsetQueryMod{offset:0},
 qm.limitQueryMod{limit:1},
 qm.orderByQueryMod{clause:"created_at desc, post_id desc"}, 
qm.loadQueryMod{relationship:"ImpartWealth", mods:[]qm.QueryMod(nil)},
 qm.whereInQueryMod{clause:"exists (\n\t\t\tselect * from ImpartWealth  
where ImpartWealth.impart_wealth_id = post.impart_wealth_id\n\t\t\tand 
ImpartWealth.screen_name like ? or ImpartWealth.email like ?) ", 
args:[]interface {}{"%j%", "%j%"}}}

Comment: @MiaMia your first mod is `nil`, the `clause` it seems like.

Comment: @MiaMia also do not post extensive code snippets into comments, they are very difficult to read. You can edit the question as many time as you want by adding details and proper syntax highliting.

Comment: @mkopriva ok, will not repeat again 

I will check the clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235152/discussion-between-mia-mia-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer.

```
if gpi.SearchKey != "" {
        where := fmt.Sprintf(`user on user.impart_wealth_id=post.impart_wealth_id 
        and (user.screen_name like ? or user.email like ? ) `)
        queryMods = append(queryMods, qm.InnerJoin(where, "%"+gpi.SearchKey+"%", "%"+gpi.SearchKey+"%"))
    }
```